# Outputs from models (trained on different data) as inputs to another model?

Tags: machine-learning, model, ensemble-learning, stacking

Let's say I want to detect **new species** of fish.

I have several models, each trained to recognize a different characteristic, e.g., the speed of known fish, the size of known fish, their known shapes, etc.
Naturally, each model will be trained on a distinct set of data: dataset_1 used to train model_speed, dataset_2 used to train model_size, dataset_3 used to train model_shape.

- Is it reasonable to combine the outputs from each of those models and use that combined output as an input to another model, such that together, my 'final' model can better understand how likely it is that it is observing a new type of fish?
- What is the name for such an approach, if it exists?
- How else would I tackle such a problem?

Comment: sounds a bit like "stacking"

Comment: @DikranMarsupial with stacking, can the models be trained on different datasets (e.g. from different sensors, from different sources, etc.)?

Comment: stacking is usually used with the same dataset (but using e.g. cross-validation predictions for the input to the combiner model).  However to train the combiner, the outputs of each "feature detector" model need to be from the same object, so it doesn't make that much difference, it would still be reasonable to view it as a special case of stacking.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial OK, thanks. So what would be the difference between Stacking and Late Fusion?

Comment: there often isn't a clear distinction between terms in machine learning.